# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I get the roles of a user that just left the server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to display some information about a user when they leave. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  channel = client.get_channel(810613415185350666)
  mention = []
  for role in member.roles:
    if role.name != "@everyone":
      mention.append(role.mention)

  b = ", ".join(mention)

  await channel.send(f"{member} has left the server. Roles: {b}")
```

Now when the event is triggered, it tells me that they've left (as expected). However, it does not show any roles even though they had several. I would assume this is because they are no longer in the server, which means they technically don't have any roles.

How would I fix this?

Comment: I wonder if `on_member_update` will be triggered for the same event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY BAD! This code works fine, but the user that was leaving simply didn't have any roles to display... I'm an idiot, sorry about that. Have a good day :)

(Would delete this question if it'd let me)

Answer (score 1):

on the doc the return is `member`, but i think that when the member left the server the argument of `on_member_remove` from `member`become `user` so it doesn't haves roles. So if that is correct you need to save in file/database the roles of the members at every `on_members_update`